# Replace string based on a dictionary

Tags: python, replace

I am trying to convert codons within my string into aminoacids.

This is what I currently have:

```
def converteRNAmParaAminoacidos(rna):
    dicionario = {'uuu':'F', 'uuc':'F','uua':'L', 'uug':'L', 'cuu':'L', 'cuc':'L', 'cua':'L', 'cug':'L', 'auu':'I', 'auc':'I', 'aua':'I', 'aug':'M', 'guu':'V', 'guc':'V', 'gua':'V', 'gug':'V', 'ucu':'S', 'ucc':'S', 'uca':'S', 'ucg':'S', 'ccu':'P', 'ccc':'P', 'cca':'P', 'ccg':'P', 'acu':'T', 'acc':'T', 'aca':'T', 'acg':'T', 'gcu':'A', 'gcu':'A', 'gcc':'A', 'gca':'A', 'gcg':'A', 'uau':'T', 'uac':'T', 'uaa':'*', 'uag':'*', 'cau':'H', 'cac':'H', 'caa':'G', 'cag':'G', 'aau':'N', 'aac':'N', 'aaa':'K', 'aag':'K', 'gau':'D', 'gac':'D', 'gaa':'E', 'gag':'E', 'ugu':'C', 'ugc':'C', 'uga':'*', 'ugg':'W', 'cgu':'R', 'cgc':'R', 'cga':'R', 'cgg':'R', 'agu':'S', 'agc':'S', 'aga':'R', 'agg':'R', 'ggu':'G', 'ggc':'G', 'gga':'G', 'ggg':'G'}
    for i,j in dicionario.iteritems():
        aminoacidos=rna.replace(i,j)
    return aminoacidos
```

However, it is not working, it only replaces the last codon.

Comment: @DaveChen `replace` returns an altered copy. Calling `a.replace()` doesn't alter a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop, you don't modify `aminoacidos`. You just keep re-setting it each iteration.

While replacement may *seem* like it will work, the order of the replacements will make a difference. Take `ucuuuc` as an example. If you first replace `ucu`, you'll end up with `Suuc`. However, if you find `cuu` first, you'll get `uLuc`, which will break subsequent replacements.

You should instead iterate over the string in chunks of three and look up each string in your dictionary:

```
# I'd choose a better variable name
dicionario = {'uuu':'F', 'uuc':'F','uua':'L', 'uug':'L', 'cuu':'L', 'cuc':'L', 'cua':'L', 'cug':'L', 'auu':'I', 'auc':'I', 'aua':'I', 'aug':'M', 'guu':'V', 'guc':'V', 'gua':'V', 'gug':'V', 'ucu':'S', 'ucc':'S', 'uca':'S', 'ucg':'S', 'ccu':'P', 'ccc':'P', 'cca':'P', 'ccg':'P', 'acu':'T', 'acc':'T', 'aca':'T', 'acg':'T', 'gcu':'A', 'gcu':'A', 'gcc':'A', 'gca':'A', 'gcg':'A', 'uau':'T', 'uac':'T', 'uaa':'*', 'uag':'*', 'cau':'H', 'cac':'H', 'caa':'G', 'cag':'G', 'aau':'N', 'aac':'N', 'aaa':'K', 'aag':'K', 'gau':'D', 'gac':'D', 'gaa':'E', 'gag':'E', 'ugu':'C', 'ugc':'C', 'uga':'*', 'ugg':'W', 'cgu':'R', 'cgc':'R', 'cga':'R', 'cgg':'R', 'agu':'S', 'agc':'S', 'aga':'R', 'agg':'R', 'ggu':'G', 'ggc':'G', 'gga':'G', 'ggg':'G'}

def converteRNAmParaAminoacidos(rna):
    aminoacidos = ''

    for i in range(0, len(rna), 3):
        aminoacidos += dicionario[rna[i:i + 3]]

    return aminoacidos
```

Or more concisely:

```
def converteRNAmParaAminoacidos(rna):
    return ''.join([dicionario[rna[i:i + 3]] for i in range(0, len(rna), 3])
```

Comment: ah thank you, it works!
sorry for the variables, i forgot to translate from portuguese the names when i posted the code xDD
just one question though, if the user doesn't enter an rna that is multiple of 3 it won't work, right? how can i make it still translate and simply ignore if the nucleotides number isn't perfect?

Answer (score 2):

In Python, the `replace` function returns a new string. What you're doing is taking the original string, doing a replacement and storing the result as `aminoacidos`. When you call `replace` again, you're not keeping the result from the previous iterations since you're calling `replace` on the original, un-altered string again.

You need to re-use `aminoacidos` like so:

```
aminoacidos = rna

for tripleto, cambio in dicionario.iteritems():
    aminoacidos = aminoacidos.replace(tripleto, cambio)
return aminoacidos
```

Comment: jozzas, thank you for helping! but i tried it and the code was translating the codons in the middle, some weren't translated. i'm not sure what happened xD

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to look into the built-in [Template](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) class, which is basically doing exactly what you want to do here.

```
from string import Template
s = Template('$who likes $what')
s.substitute(who='tim', what='kung pao')
'tim likes kung pao'
d = {'who':'tom', 'what':'moo shoo'}
s.substute(d) #pass same keywords as a dictionay
'tom likes moo shoo'
```

Comment: theodox, that's very interesting, i'm a huge noob at programming in general and i've never heard of that template class, i'll try and use it, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are saving only the last replace to the `aminoacidos` variable. I changed your code to replace the `rna` string and set it to `rna`. It should work.

```
def converteRNAmParaAminoacidos(rna):
    dicionario = {'uuu':'F', 'uuc':'F','uua':'L', 'uug':'L', 'cuu':'L', 'cuc':'L', 'cua':'L', 'cug':'L', 'auu':'I', 'auc':'I', 'aua':'I', 'aug':'M', 'guu':'V', 'guc':'V', 'gua':'V', 'gug':'V', 'ucu':'S', 'ucc':'S', 'uca':'S', 'ucg':'S', 'ccu':'P', 'ccc':'P', 'cca':'P', 'ccg':'P', 'acu':'T', 'acc':'T', 'aca':'T', 'acg':'T', 'gcu':'A', 'gcu':'A', 'gcc':'A', 'gca':'A', 'gcg':'A', 'uau':'T', 'uac':'T', 'uaa':'*', 'uag':'*', 'cau':'H', 'cac':'H', 'caa':'G', 'cag':'G', 'aau':'N', 'aac':'N', 'aaa':'K', 'aag':'K', 'gau':'D', 'gac':'D', 'gaa':'E', 'gag':'E', 'ugu':'C', 'ugc':'C', 'uga':'*', 'ugg':'W', 'cgu':'R', 'cgc':'R', 'cga':'R', 'cgg':'R', 'agu':'S', 'agc':'S', 'aga':'R', 'agg':'R', 'ggu':'G', 'ggc':'G', 'gga':'G', 'ggg':'G'}
    for i,j in dicionario.iteritems():
        rna = rna.replace(i, j)
    return rna
```

Comment: thank you for the help, iurisilvio, but i couldn't make it work like that =(